# Android game freezing when turning on parent with a large number of childs

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I making android game with Unity but I met problem with a large number of objects. The game has an inventory system. When I add an item to the inventory when there are already many objects its working fine. But if close page with inventory and open again game will freeze every time for 1-2 second(depending on the number of items). If you check the profiler, you can see that most of the time it takes to render these items. But not all of objects not captured of the camera.
How it works? Does Unity render all elements?  Only 20 objects out of all get into the camera and, in theory, the render should take less time or am I missing something? If all objects are rendered, then how can I speed up the render time or somehow distribute the work. I using UI for inventory system. Also i using SetActive method to hide pages.

I thought about making a loop that would set SetActive to false for objects that are outside the camera and put it in FixedUpdate, but I not think that this will solve the problem, because with a large number of items the loop will run longer, and inserting a loop into Update and FixedUpdate is not recommended. Maybe there is a flag in the Unity that allows you to render object even if SetActive is false? Any thoughts? Sprites already have a fairly small resolution. Each item cell has two text objects and two images. Parent is a Scrollable container with gameobject content which contains it all cells.

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow! Adding code and/or image(s) would make the question more readable and consequently you would have a better chance of getting an answer. As for the question, Occlusion Culling seems to deal with not rendering certain objects not visible to the camera. https://docs.unity3d.com/Manual/OcclusionCulling.html

Comment: @Francesco-FL Occlusion Culling will not work as it only affects 3D objects. UI elements are handled by a different pipeline in Unity.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is a pretty commun issue with how [Unity UI works](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=_wxitgdx-UI&t=1423s). (you can check at [29:30](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=_wxitgdx-UI&t=1770s) where he talks about scroll view). Short answer is yes, Unity renders UI even if it's outside of the camera. You can follow the video's guideline to help with UI performance in general. My advice is to pool your items and only show what you need to. Even better would be to not use Unity's Scroll view, which is a mess in term of performance.

I haven't used [this package](https://github.com/MdIqubal/Recyclable-Scroll-Rect), but you could check it out. It's supposed to be quite performant and recycles objects so you only render what you need. (and it's free)

Side note, Unity's UI Toolkit also has a ListView which pools items and rebinds them, but this is a whole other thing to learn.